# How to obtain a puppet report?

Tags: puppet

Puppet version : 2016 / 4.8

Currently I use the puppet console to view the reports that are generated for the Node. Problem with this view is that it displays the log items one entry at a time. I can go to "Events" and filter by event status (it says `Failed`) but it still does not provide me the control that I need.
Is there anyway I can pull down the entire log file for one particular server for a certain time range?
I attempted `"/pdb/query/v4/reports" uri` but my Puppet master does not seem to support it.